# Witt Vector Motivation for Teichmüller representatives

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm quite comfortable with the motivation for Teichmüller representatives given in this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/113943/69608), but I'm curious about something said in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt_vector#Detailed_motivational_sketch):

> The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can be expanded as (formal) power series in $p$:
>
> $$a_0 + a_1 p^1 + a_2 p^2 + \cdots,$$
>
> where $a_i$ are usually taken from the integer interval $[0,p-1]=\{0, 1, \ldots, p-1\}.$ Of course, this power series usually will not converge in $\mathbb{R}$ using the standard metric on the reals, but it will converge in $\mathbb{Z}_p,$ with the $p$-adic metric. We will sketch a method of defining ring operations for such power series.
>
> Letting $a+b$ be denoted by $c$, one might consider the following definition for addition:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> c_0 &\equiv a_0+b_0 && \bmod p \\
> c_0+c_1 p &\equiv (a_0+b_0) + (a_1 +b_1)p && \bmod p^2 \\
> c_0+c_1 p+c_2 p^2 &\equiv (a_0+b_0) + (a_1 +b_1)p+(a_2+b_2) p^2 &&\bmod p^3
> \end{align}$$
>
> and one could make a similar definition for multiplication. **However, this is not a closed formula, since the new coefficients are not in the allowed set $[0,p-1]$**.

I've bolded the last line above to emphasize it. This example is used to motivate choosing a new set of representatives, but I don't see the problem. If I carry out the process of solving those equations for the sum $c=a+b$ with, say, $p=7, a = 55 = 5\cdot 7 + 5$ and $b = 46 = 4\cdot 7 + 6$, I obtain values of $c_0 = 4, c_1 = 3, c_2=1$ which are within the allowed set $\{0, \ldots, 6\}$. I get the same thing if I use addition with carrying. I don't see how any other example can fail to be closed in the sense above. What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding here?

Comment: The equations given there for $c_i$ are more naive than you think:  in your example, they say that $(5 \cdot 7 + 5) + (4 \cdot 7 + 6) = 9 \cdot 7 + 11$.  Converting this into $1 \cdot 7^2 + 3 \cdot 7 + 4$ requires carrying, which is a finicky piecewise-defined operation that we want to avoid.

Comment: Perhaps this will better explain how non-algebraic the carrying operation is:  given two two-digit numbers $a_1 a_0$ and $b_1 b_0$ written in base $p$, you know how to express their sum $c_2 c_1 c_0$ in base $p$ by carrying.  This process involves working in $\mathbb Z$ and checking various inequalities, e.g. whether $a_0 + b_0 \geq p$.  Can you find a way to calculate the digits $c_0, c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb F_p$ in terms of the digits $a_0, a_1, b_0, b_1 \in \mathbb F_p$ without making any reference to $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @RaviFernando That is clear and makes perfect sense. The article meant to imply “closed” as in F_p operations, not merely F_p output. I feel like it’s misleading, as written, if not incorrect. I will gladly accept your comments as an answer if you submit them as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations given there for $c_i$ are more naive than you think: in your example, they say that $(5 \cdot 7 + 5) + (4 \cdot 7 + 6) = 9\cdot 7 + 11$.  Converting this into $1\cdot 7^2 + 3 \cdot 7 + 4$ requires carrying, which is a finicky piecewise-defined operation that we want to avoid.

Perhaps this will better explain how non-algebraic the carrying operation is: given two two-digit numbers $a_1 a_0$ and $b_1 b_0$ written in base $p$, you know how to express their sum $c_2 c_1 c_0$ in base $p$ by carrying. This process involves working in $\mathbb Z$ and checking various inequalities, e.g. whether $a_0 + b_0 \geq p$. Can you find a way to calculate the digits $c_0, c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb F_p$ in terms of the digits $a_0, a_1, b_0, b_1 \in \mathbb F_p$ without making any reference to $\mathbb Z$?

The boldfaced sentence seems to be mixing up two senses of the word "closed".  On the one hand, base-$p$ expansions are not **closed under the operation of naive addition** (without carrying), since for example $9 \cdot 7 + 11$ is not a valid base-$p$ expansion.  (This is of course just a reflection of the fact that the subset $\{0, \dots, p-1\} \subset \mathbb Z$ is not closed under addition.)  On the other hand, it is difficult to give an explicit **closed formula** for the operation of addition with carrying (as opposed to an algorithm for computing it).